# Сypress ignores the index of the letter in the string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a test:

```
describe('string component works correctly', () => {
  ...
  it('reverses the string correctly', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/recursion');

    const inputString = 'Hello';
    const reversedString = 'olleH';

    cy.get('input')
      .type(inputString)
      .should('have.value', inputString);

    cy.contains('button', 'wrap').click();

    cy.wait(1000)

    cy.get('.circles').each((circle, index) => {
      const indexStr = reversedString[index]
      cy.wrap(circle).should('have.text', indexStr)
    })
  });
})
```

I am interested in this test:

```
cy.get('.circles').each((circle, index) => {
      const indexStr = reversedString[index]
      cy.wrap(circle).should('have.text', indexStr)
    })
```

I get that error:

```
assertexpected <div.circles.string_circles__AE6EW> to have text o, but the text was olleH
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<div.circles.string_circles__AE6EW>' to have text 'o', but the text was 'olleH'
cypress/e2e/stringTest.cy.js:27:23
  25 |     cy.get('.circles').each((circle, index) => {
  26 |       const indexStr = reversedString[index]
> 27 |       cy.wrap(circle).should('have.text', indexStr)
     |                       ^
  28 |     })
  29 |   });
  30 | })
```

it as if doesnt see [index] after reversedString

initially I had the code: cy.wrap(circle).should('have.text', reversedString[index]), then i try to use const, but it didn't work

Comment: solutin: ```cy.get('.circles').each((circle, index) => {
      const letter = reversedString.slice(index)
      const indexStr = letter
      cy.wrap(circle).should('have.text', indexStr)
    })```